# SELECTION SORT USING POINTERS AND FUNCTIONS IN C

Tags: c, function, sorting, pointers, selection

```
#include<stdio.h>
void functt(int *,int );
int main {
int n;
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("Enter the elements of the array");
int i;
int arr[n];
int *ptr;
ptr=arr;
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",(p+i));
}
printf("The array elemets are as follows");
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    printf("%d",*(p+i));
}
void functt(arr,n);
return 0;
}

void functt(int *,int n)
{
    int i,j,min;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        min=i;

        for (j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(*(p+min)>*(p+j))
            {
                min=j;
            }

        }
    int temp=*(p+min);
    *(p+min)=*(p+j);
    *(p+j)=temp;
}
```

ERRORS:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2iLq.png

Can't run this code due to these errors
PROGRAM IS TO USE SELECTION SORT VIA POINTERS AND FUNCTIONS.
LOGIC SEEMS TO BE CORRECT I THINK BUT IT GIVES SOME ERRORS AS IN THE PNG ATTACHED ABOVE.

Comment: `void functt(int *,int );`. bad syntax for function decleration. fix it. `void functt(int* p_arr, int size);`
You cant declare array with unknown or chngable size!!  supply const literal `int arr[const literal or number];`

Comment: @Adam You don't need to name the parameters in a function declaration, just stating the types is fine. You don't even need to name a parameter in a function definition if the parameter isn't used in the function.

Comment: Please, [don't shout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There were quite a lot of errors in here. You had named your array pointer ptr but then tried to use one called "p" instead. You had missing brackets in a few places. If you lay out your code nicely, these errors are much easier to see. I have fixed the compile errors in your code and re-arranged the sort function.

Note : I've made a very minimal set of changes in the hope you can see what I did. This is not necessarily the best way to write this code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void functt(int *,int );

int main () {
    int n;

    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter the elements of the array: ");

    int arr[n];
    int *ptr;
    ptr=arr;

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",(ptr+i));
    }

    printf("\nThe array elements are as follows: ");
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",*(ptr+i));
    }

    functt(arr,n);

    printf("\nThe array elements are sorted as follows: ");
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",*(ptr+i));
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

void functt(int *p,int n)
{
    int min;

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        min=i;

        for (int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(*(p+min)>*(p+j))
            {
                int temp=*(p+min);
                *(p+min)=*(p+j);
                *(p+j)=temp;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I write this solution in order to dilver some important tips for C programming and any other language.

1. The code must me readable, this can be achieved with `functions` and giving them ameaningful names.
2. Functions shouldnt be long and complicated (seperate the logic) let each function do 1 task.
3. Always check parameters (those who comes from the outside of your application like user inputs or any other `API` users).
4. Checking and validating function arguments `affect performance`! when there is no need to check we dont check. e.g. we must check the return value of `system call` `malloc()`, because if we fail to allocate we dont want to crash the whole program!
5. Use `size_t` when you are talking about sizes which >= 0 !
6. Use `const` (you can protect the address and the value of the parameter) in function decleration and let the compiler helps you enforcing language rules and your own rules!
7. Think performance (just if you need, but C was borned for performance :-)), accessing `arrays` like pointers with the `derefernce operator`, `astrisc or star *` is more faster than operator `subscribt []`
8. Good luck. C is one of the most eligant and powerful language that ever made!

**The Code Snippet**

```
enter code here
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/*swap two int varibles*/
void f_swap(int* lhs, int* rhs)
{
    int temp = *rhs;
    *rhs = *lhs;
    *lhs = temp;
}
/*status enum*/
typedef enum E_STAT {
    success_status = 0x0,
    allocation_failed = 0x1,
    invalid_user_inputs = 0x2,
    /*... you can add if you want/need*/
    failure_status
}E_STAT;

const char* f_status_to_str(E_STAT stat)
{
    static const char* STATUS_MSG[4] = {
                             "success_status",
                             "allocation_failure",
                             "invalid_user_inputs",
                             "failure_status" };

    return STATUS_MSG[stat];
}


void f_fill_array(int* p_ret_arr, size_t arr_size)
{
    printf("Enter the elements of the array below:\n");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arr_size; ++i)
    {
        /*scanf("%d", &p_ret_arr[i]);*/ /*or we can take them in the form next line*/
        printf("Enter the -%lu- element:", i);
        scanf("%d", (p_ret_arr + i));
        //puts("");
    }
}

void f_sel_sort(int* const p_arr, size_t arr_size)
{
    size_t i, j, min_idx;

    /* One by one move boundary of unsorted subarray  */
    for (i = 0; i < arr_size - 1; i++)
    {
        /* Find the minimum element in unsorted array  */
        min_idx = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < arr_size; ++j)
        {
            if (p_arr[j] < p_arr[min_idx])
            {
                min_idx = j;
            }
        }

        /*Swap the found minimum element with the first element  */
        f_swap(&p_arr[min_idx], &p_arr[i]);
    }
}

void f_print_array(const int* const p_arr, size_t arr_size)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j < arr_size; ++j)
    {
        printf("%d ", *(p_arr + j));
    }
}

/*allocate new int array on the heap (dyn allocation)*/
int* f_allocate(size_t arr_size)
{
    int* p_ret = NULL;
    return (p_ret=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * arr_size));
}

E_STAT f_get_arr(int** p_ret_arr, size_t* arr_size)
{
    E_STAT stat;

    printf("Please enter array size below:\n");
    scanf("%lu", arr_size);
    /*recomended to check the arr_size and do some limiting on this variable if you wish*/

    *p_ret_arr = f_allocate(*arr_size);
    if (!(*p_ret_arr))
    {
        stat = allocation_failed;
        return stat;
    }

    f_fill_array(*p_ret_arr, *arr_size);
    stat = success_status;
    return stat;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    size_t arr_size = 0;
    int* arr = NULL;
    E_STAT stat;

    stat = f_get_arr(&arr, &arr_size);
    if (stat != success_status)
    {
        printf("Error: %s\n", f_status_to_str(stat));
        abort();
    }

    f_sel_sort(arr, arr_size);
    printf("Sorted array elements:\n");
    f_print_array(arr, arr_size);

    return 0;
}
```